# How to delete photos from local disk on Mac without deleting in iCloud?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, photos

I have around 5 GB for photos on iCloud and it gets automatically downloaded to my MacBook which is only 256 GB. Is there a way to have the photos on iCloud without having them on the local machine. Something like how Google Photos does. Unless specified, it doesn't download the photos on to the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Photos Preferences → iCloud → Optimise Mac Storage.

> Optimize Mac Storage: To save space on your Mac by storing full-resolution originals in iCloud and keeping smaller versions on the computer when needed, select this option.

https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/pht5156cc968/mac

Caches are purgeable space, which will be reclaimed by the system automatically as free disk space decreases.